# Can I mock the class name of an RSpec double?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have an RSpec test file where I have created a double that allows a method and returns a value.  In my Ruby application code I have used the code

```
if some_object.class == ClassName
```

to filter out unwanted instances of other classes.

The code works and gives the correct results but will not pass the RSpec test as the double gets filtered out during the test as it's classname is RSpec::Mocks::Double.

I have looked around but can't fin how to mock the class name of the actual double.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stub `class` invocation:

```
expect(some_object).to receive(:class).and_return(ClassName)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, thought I had tried this solution but I must have got the syntax slightly off but yours works a treat.